# Avoid "what you tried" comments?

Tags: support, feature-request

Since when I joined, I have noticed that many users post questions without any reference, and others comment "show us the code" or "post what you have done".
Isn't there any way to avoid such comments? This will benefit both the asker and answerers.

I know Stack Overflow has such messages while posting a question but somehow it is getting ignored I think.

It would be helpful if there is a separate section for "What work has been done" or "What has been tried already". What do you think?

Comment: What do you mean by "a separate section"? Section of what? The way to avoid such comments is for questioners to ask decent questions with enough information...

Comment: By the way, your post reminds me of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/reject-an-already-approved-suggested-edit-when-rolling-it-back). Use backticks for codes only please.

Comment: @JonSkeet my English is not good, he might say that question form could be reformatted and one section be added for what you have done!! This way the OP reminds its a necessary (if applicable) part of the question.

Comment: @JonSkeet oh sorry for my previous comment! I didn't recognize you until I checked your profile! Yes Section of what? really!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure it can be avoided.  Downvote the question for being "unclear", that helps avoid having other SO users waste time on the question and helps focus attention to answerable questions.  And vote to close the question as "Too broad" or "Off topic" (4th bullet), that helps avoid SO users posting blind guesses at an answer and produce a useless Q+A.  This is the approach recommended by SE, it avoids complaints.

But you can't really fix human traits, SO users tend to try to be helpful even if the questioner doesn't make enough of an effort to help us help him.  You can't beat that out with a stick.  Just flag the comment if you want to use the stick anyway.

Comment: Can we put such posters togethher with the 'we want comments on downvotes' set in a ring together?

Comment: @MartinJames: You want to make a mint selling tickets?