# Why does my Stack Overflow login not work on other, linked, Stack Exchange sites? (in Firefox only)

Tags: support, login, google, firefox

I have an **account on Stackoverflow.com, and other, linked, Stack Exchange sites**. The Stack Overflow account has it's own username/password, plus I have associated it to my Google login.

While I am able to log into Stackoverflow.com with either my Google Login or the Stack Overflow account credentials, on all other sites, I can only log in with the Google Account.

**Why do my Stack Overflow credentials not work on my other Stack Exchange sites?**

Note: I experience this only in Firefox (Using NoScript and Ghostery), but all works well in Chrome. Weird.

Comment: "What have you tried?" :trollface:

Comment: @Zac Well, I have tried to login on, for example on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/. It will not accept my password from stackoverflow.com. However, if I login with the "google" option, I instantly am logged in as me. I need to say, that these two (and others) accounts are "linked".

Comment: Yes, I was just trolling, in relation to [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284653/avoid-what-you-tried-comments) today asked question. BTW are you using Firefox?

Comment: Yes, I am, and I use NoScript and Ghostery. Hey, it seems to matter... I could not reproduce the behaviour in Chrome. I am instantly logged in! What could be the difference here?

Comment: I myself experienced SO login issues with Firefox, I was able to solve by cleaning the cookies cache.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stack Exchange sites have some issues with Firefox and cookies; you can solve login problems by cleaning the browser cache.